# bash + how to append path to the end of the line according to existing path

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

The following configuration file (*example 1*) isn't configured as it should be.

Each line in file should contain the `/grid/sdX` (`a` to `z`)
as described in *example 2*.

I need to find a way to write a bash script for this task. How to append the missing `/grid/sdX` in the end of the lines?

example 1

```
more dfs_data_dir_mount.hist


/grid/sdk/hadoop/hdfs/data,/
/grid/sdi/hadoop/hdfs/data,/
/grid/sdh/hadoop/hdfs/data,/
/grid/sdc/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdc
/grid/sdj/hadoop/hdfs/data,/
/grid/sde/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sde
/grid/sdd/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdd
/grid/sdb/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdb
/grid/sdf/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdf
/grid/sdg/hadoop/hdfs/data,/
```

expected results (example 2)

```
/grid/sdk/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdk
/grid/sdi/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdi
/grid/sdh/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdh
/grid/sdc/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdc
/grid/sdj/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdj
/grid/sde/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sde
/grid/sdd/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdd
/grid/sdb/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdb
/grid/sdf/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdf
/grid/sdg/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -Ei 's~^(/[^/]+/[^/]+)(.*,)/$~\1\2\1~' dfs_data_dir_mount.hist
```

- `~` - treated as `sed` subcommand separator
- `[^/]+` - match one or more character(s) except slash `/`
- `^` `$` - are the start and end of the line respectively

Answer (score 5):

I was able to accomplish this with the following awk command:

```
awk -F'/' '{OFS="/";}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,"grid",$3}' input
```

`awk`

- `-F'/'` - Delimit input by `/`
- `{OFS="/";}` - Delimit output by `/`
- `{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,"grid",$3}'` - Print `/grid/sd*/hadoop/hdfs/data,/` (fields taken from input) and `grid/sd*` (manually inputting `grid` and adding field 3 again)

Comment: nice but awk cant update the file itself ( as sed -i .... ) , so need to send results to other file and then copy it to the orig file

Comment: @yael yea, although apparently `gawk` supports `-i inplace` from `v4.1.0` and later.

Answer (score 5):

`awk`:

```
awk -F/ -v OFS='/' '!$NF {$0=$0 $2 OFS $3}; 1'
```

- `-F/ -v OFS='/'` sets the input and output field separator as `/`
- `!$NF {$0=$0 $2 OFS $3}; 1` if the last field is empty, we're rebuiling the record in the desired format. `1` is truthy in `awk` and is to print the records.

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
/grid/sdk/hadoop/hdfs/data,/
/grid/sdi/hadoop/hdfs/data,/
/grid/sdh/hadoop/hdfs/data,/
/grid/sdc/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdc
/grid/sdj/hadoop/hdfs/data,/
/grid/sde/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sde
/grid/sdd/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdd
/grid/sdb/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdb
/grid/sdf/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdf
/grid/sdg/hadoop/hdfs/data,/

% awk -F/ -v OFS='/' '!$NF {$0=$0 $2 OFS $3}; 1' file.txt
/grid/sdk/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdk
/grid/sdi/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdi
/grid/sdh/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdh
/grid/sdc/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdc
/grid/sdj/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdj
/grid/sde/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sde
/grid/sdd/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdd
/grid/sdb/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdb
/grid/sdf/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdf
/grid/sdg/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdg
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl oneliner:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's;^/(grid/sd.)/hadoop/hdfs/data,/\K$;$1;' input
```

Match the string, picking up the `grid/sdX` from the start on the way, then forget (`\K`) the main part of the string, but still match the end of line `$`, which is then replaced by the part captured by the parenthesis and available in `$1`.

`-i.bak` makes the changes in-place, and saves the original file with the extension `.bak`.

```
$ cat input
/grid/sdc/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdc
/grid/sdj/hadoop/hdfs/data,/
/grid/sde/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sde
$ perl -i.bak  -pe 's:^/(grid/sd.)/hadoop/hdfs/data,/\K$:$1:' input
$ cat input
/grid/sdc/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdc
/grid/sdj/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sdj
/grid/sde/hadoop/hdfs/data,/grid/sde
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (field-based) perl approach using the `.=` string concatenation operator:

```
perl -F/ -lpe '$_ .= "$F[1]/$F[2]" unless defined $F[7]' dfs_data_dir_mount.hist
```